# Add support for SASS/SCSS syntax highlighting

Tags: feature-request

Please, add support for [Sass/SCSS](https://sass-lang.com/) syntax highlighting.

> Sass is the most mature, stable, and powerful professional grade CSS extension language in the world.

Comment: Please read the linked faq, under "How do I report a bug or request a new language?".

Comment: @ShadowWizard I've followed a guide from the "If you want a language added" section...

Comment: @ShadowWizard I see that I've probably used incorrect meta site. Do I need to create the same request on StackOverflow Meta?

Comment: Yes you might have better luck there since it's applying to SO only.